# Application Loader: No eligible applications were found

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

I am trying to upload my application to the apple app store, but! I've set my application ID, certificate etc... then build signed application step by step according to apple howtos. In iTunes Connect I've registered my application record and yes! I've pressed the blue button: "Ready to upload binary" and my application status is: "Waiting for upload". I've even received an email, that I can now upload my binary. But! Even if I try to run setup wizard and enter correct info in Application loader I still get the message:

```
No eligible applications were found.
```

WHY!? I'm getting desperate about this. I've spent more than 5 days with trying to repeat, making everything step by step again, even trying to validate my application via XCode 4.0.2 fails, but with the message: No suitable application records were found.

please anybody help! I've written about this problem to apple tech support 4 days ago, but they haven't replied till now! I'm starting regret the money for this "Apple developer gibberish".

Comment: Is there any resolution to this problem?  I'm faced with the same issue.

Comment: Problem has been resolved itself by migrating from SnowLeopard to Lion and to new XCode 4.1 (for Lion). Possible problem could be that I had unstripped (with ppc code) Growl library in my app, because when I've installed XCode 4.1 it warned me about this - I mean not concretely, but it warned me that I have not allowed ppc code in my code.

Answer (score 33):

Make sure your status isn't "Prepare for Upload" and is actually "Waiting for Upload."

On the app's page in iTC, you have to click "Ready to Upload binary" and it'll ask you about encryption.  After that you should be good to go.

Comment: That's what I had already done. Even apple tech support doesn't know to help me to resolve this problem. I did  fresh install with XCode only and reproduced all the necessary steps with the same faulty result :(

Comment: This little difference in messages wasted about an hr out of my day until I read this.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and I went back, and I noticed the "load binary" button at the bottom of the page rather than the top. I guess I thought I had already clicked that but hadn't. There's a chance you might have over looked that like I did.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the version number in your plist file matches that of the Application on iTunes Connect. Also, confirm matching Bundle Indentifiers.

Make sure you are logging in with the same account. I know, that sounds silly, but I manage multiple accounts for different clients and have done that before.

Comment: Version number (1.0) is the same. Should it be written as string or as a plain number? I don't have a multiple accounts. Anyway, I don't understand why Application Loader doesn't see this application record without opening created package. As far I understand it correctly Application Loader should read Application records from iTunes Connect and then offer to upload binary package to desired record, it shouldn't have access to my projects.

Comment: I too manage different accounts for different clients, and ensuring I logged in with the correct account solved it for me. Thank you MP!

Comment: I had a similar experience, using the wrong account to attempt a validation. One thing that makes this a little confusing is the fact that you can use a single login for the Dev Center and your profile management (and pick a team), but must use separate logins for each iTunes Connect account. Be nice if there were a more unified environment on the Apple side, or at least a unified interface.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's website:

Troubleshooting: If Xcode doesn’t find an iTunes Connect application record for your application, the “No suitable application records were found” dialog appears. This dialog also appears when the application record state is not at least Waiting for Upload.
Ensure an application record exists for your application in iTunes Connect.
Ensure the application record status is at least Waiting to Upload.

You can find the link here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/articles/validating_apps.html

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing occur when you upload a binary files via Application Loader.

After Submitted Itunes said "Invalid binary". and you again Upload an application at that time  , then Application Loader said **Application Loader: No eligible applications were found**

for solve this Issue:

1) Log in https://itunesconnect.apple.com

2) go to -> manage your application

3) you see that red button with "**Invalid Binary**" click on It.

4) scroll down and you will see "**Upload Binary**" option. click it.

5) Itunes ask that did you change any encryption in previous binary give the answer appropriate.

6) then click "**done**".

7) now Again you try with Application Loader It will work normally.

I try to upload my application 4-5 times i had go through this steps. i hope that will help you.